# (.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_13'

Tags: arduino

Using NewPing.h seems to be the main issue.

Code:

```
#include <LedControl.h>
#include "pitches.h"
#include "SR04.h"
#include "NewPing.h"

#define TRIGGER_PIN 13

#define ECHO_PIN 8

#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

long duration;
int distance; 

int DIN = 12;
int CS =  11;
int CLK = 10;

LedControl lc=LedControl(DIN,CLK,CS,0);

const int buzzer = 9;

void setup(){
 lc.shutdown(0,false);       //The MAX72XX is in power-saving mode on startup
 lc.setIntensity(0,15);      // Set the brightness to maximum value
 lc.clearDisplay(0);         // and clear the display
 pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);    //buzzer shit
 pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an OUTPUT
 pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an INPUT
 Serial.begin(9600); // // Serial Communication is starting with 9600 of baudrate speed
}

void loop(){ 
    unsigned int uS = sonar.ping();
    Serial.print(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);
    
    byte a[8]=   {0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x18,};
    byte b[8]= {0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x18,0x00,};
    byte c[8]=   {0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x18,}; //done
    byte d[8] = {0x00,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,}; //done
    byte e[8]=   {0x18,0x5a,0x3c,0x18,0x18,0x24,0x5a,0x18,}; //done
    byte f[8]=   {0x99,0x5a,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x5a,0x99,}; //done
    byte g[8]= {0x99,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x99,};
    byte h[8]= {0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x18,};
    
    if (uS <= 20){

    printByte(a);
    
    tone(buzzer, 1000);
     
    delay(100);

    printByte(b);
    noTone(buzzer);
    
    delay(100);

    printByte(c);
    tone(buzzer, 1000);    

    delay(100);

    printByte(d);
    noTone(buzzer);

    delay(100);
   
    printByte(e);
    tone(buzzer, 1000);    
    
    delay (100);
    
    printByte(f);
    noTone(buzzer);
    
    delay (100);
    
    printByte(g);
    tone(buzzer, 1000);
    
    delay (100);
    
    printByte(h);
    noTone(buzzer);
    
    delay(1000);
    }

}


void printByte(byte character [])
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    lc.setRow(0,i,character[i]);
  }
}
```

The main thing that stands out in the error is the line

"(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_13'

C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_789753\libraries\NewPing\NewPing.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here".

However, I don't exactly know how to solve it.

Comment: you have an interrupt handler conflict. tone() uses the same timer interrupt as NewPing

Comment: What Arduino are you using? Some libraries support using a different timer. I once had the same problem when I was trying to actuate a servo while at the same controlling a ledmatrix. Installing a servo library that runs on a different timer solved the problem for me.